# Update with Inner join issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know whats wrong with my query but I get this error:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON  a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2' at line 4
```

Here's the sql that i am trying:

```
UPDATE table1 AS a
Set a.Closed = 2

From a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON  a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2
WHERE number in (01809076,02170039);
```

Comment: does number belong to table a or b?

Comment: I'm not a MySQL guy, but I think, that `FROM ... JOIN` in `UPDATE` query is not valid even in MySQL.

Comment: @bonCodigo number is belong to table b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `MySQL`, the syntax for `UPDATE` with join is like this. (*no `FROM` clause*)

```
UPDATE  table1 AS a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON  a.column1 = b.column1 AND 
                a.column2 = b.column2
SET     a.Closed = 2
WHERE   b.number in (01809076,02170039);
```

the one you are currently using is for `T-SQL`

Comment: when I use this syntax, the platform that I am using hangs. I am using SQLYog. I don't know what happens. :(

Comment: @JRC are you updating on large database?

Comment: yes po, I don't know why it takes time to load and YOG hangs.

Comment: then you lack index on the columns. you need to define index on `table1.column1`,`table1.column2`,`table2.column1`,`table2.column2`

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query like this :

UPDATE table1 
Set Closed = 2

From table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON  a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2
WHERE number in (01809076,02170039);

It will definitely work

Thanks
Uttam

Comment: I still got this error- Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From receivinglog a INNER JOIN bartran b ON a.batchid = b.batchid AND a.type = b' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily:

```
UPDATE  table1,table2 
SET     table1.Closed = 2
WHERE   table1.column1 = b.column1 AND table1.column2 = table2.column2 AND table2.number in (01809076,02170039) ;
```